# Python, paquetes typing y typeguard con listas, no evalúa el tipo de dato de la lista

Tags: python, validación

Buen día,

Estoy utilizando los paquetes `typing` y `typeguard` para revisar que los argumentos de mis métodos reciben el tipo de dato correcto. Estoy utilizando Python 3.10

Tengo dos clases, `ClassA` y `ClassB` y la clase B recibe una lista de elementos de clase A como argumento. Con el fin de proveer un ejemplo completo, eliminé todos los métodos de mis clases y las abrevié para reproducir el problema (Por lo que tal vez no tenga sentido el código en sí), lo único que me interesa es poder hacer la validación de forma correcta utilizando `typeguard`

Al utilizar `@typechecked` normalmente revisa que los argumentos de entrada y de salida cumplan con el tipo de dato configurado, por ejemplo:

```
from typing import Final, List, Dict, TypeVar, Type, Sequence
from typeguard import typechecked

#Class A
@typechecked
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self, s: str) -> None:
        self._s = s.lower()

x = ClassA(2)
```

Devuelve:

```
TypeError: type of argument "s" must be str; got int instead
```

Porque `ClassA` recibió como argumento `2` en lugar de un `string`

Pero ¿Cómo se puede utilizar con una lista de instancias de otra clase? Por más que busco no encuentro información al respecto

```
from typing import Final, List, Dict, TypeVar, Type, Sequence
from typeguard import typechecked

TClassA = TypeVar("TClassA", bound="ClassA")

#Class A
@typechecked
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self, s: str) -> None:
        self._s = s.lower()
        
#Class B
@typechecked
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, segments: Sequence[TClassA], seg_prefix: str = 'gSeg_', seg_offset: int = 1):
        if seg_offset < 0:
            raise TypeError('The "seg_offset" argument must be a positive integer')

        self.segment = [ClassA(seg._s) for seg in segments]
        self.seg_prefix = seg_prefix
        self.seg_offset = seg_offset

x = ClassB([2,2])
```

Lo que esperaría que devolviera es un error diciendo que la lista en `ClassB` no es de tipo `TClassA` pero ignora el tipo de elemento de la lista e intenta obtener `self.segment` y me devuelve el siguiente error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_s'
```

En la página de la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) aparece el siguiente ejemplo:

```
T = TypeVar('T', int, float)

def vec2(x: T, y: T) -> List[T]:
    return [x, y]

def keep_positives(vector: Sequence[T]) -> List[T]:
    return [item for item in vector if item > 0]
```

Pero están utilizando `int` y `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posiblemente se trate de un bug de la versión de `typeguard` que estás usando, relacionado con el uso de `TypeVar`. Aparentemente ese bug ha sido resuelto a partir de la versión 2.13.0, como puedes leer en [la documentación de ese paquete](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versionhistory.html?highlight=typevar#version-history):

> #### 2.13.0 (2021-10-11)
>
> - [... (editado) ...]
> - Fixed broken `TypeVar` checks – variance is now (correctly) disregarded, and only bound types and constraints are checked against (but type variable resolution is not done)

Yo he probado tu ejemplo en Google Colab y efectivamente ocurre el error que describes en la pregunta. Pero es que Google Colab tiene instalada la versión 2.7.1 como puede verse aqui:

```
>>> !pip freeze |grep typeguard
typeguard==2.7.1
```

### Edición

No es un problema de versión. He instalado la última (2.13.3) y sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema. Supongo que no tenemos del todo claro el funcionamiento de `TypeVar` en este caso. La [documentación](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html?highlight=typevar#supported-typing-types) dice lo siguiente sobre este tipo:

> **TypeVar**:  Constraints, bound types and co/contravariance are supported but custom generic types are not (due to type erasure)

lo cual es un galimatías incomprensible para mí.

### Posible solución

¿Por qué estás usando `TypeVar` para empezar? Esto suele utilizarse para describir tipos *Genéricos*, pero no es este tu caso.

Podrías no usar `TypeVar` en absoluto, y en cambio usar el tipo `ClassA` directamente así:

```
#Class B
@typechecked
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, segments: Sequence[ClassA], seg_prefix: str = 'gSeg_', seg_offset: int = 1):
         ...
```

Con ese cambio, el chequeo de tipo ya sucede correctamente, pues ahora obtienes el error:

```
TypeError: type of argument "segments"[0] must be __main__.ClassA; got int instead
```

**Nota**: Al poner `ClassA` como tipo de la lista, admites también cualquier clase que herede de `ClassA`. Lo digo por si esta era la razón por la que habías usado un *bound* `TypeVar`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, estoy utilizando la version 13.3 de `typeguard`. La razón por la que utilizo `TypeVar` es porque algunos métodos de la clase devuelven instancias de la misma clase y ni `typing` ni `typeguard` soportan `Self` (Leí en la documentación que en Python 3.11 lo van a agregar, pero la forma de hacerlo ahora es utilizando `TypeVar`). Lo que entiendo de la documentación es que al utilizar `TypeVar` se crea un alias del tipo de dato de la clase que puede ser utilizado para revisar que el `return` tenga la clase correcta. Pero al parecer no funciona en la entrada

Comment: Tuve que utilizar las clases originales en los argumentos y `TypeVar` (El alias de las clases originales) en los `return` cuando salga Python 3.11 podré quitar `TypeVar` y utilizar `Self`. Gracias por la ayuda, eso resolvió mi problema

Comment: Sobre el tema del _type erasure_, lo que viene a decir es que en listas (y colecciones en general) desaparece toda referencia del tipo de sus elementos, por lo que no puede chequearse el tipo en tiempo de ejecución. Hay que recurrir a los sistemas de anotaciones como [_phantom types_](https://phantom-types.readthedocs.io) para determinar si un objeto es _admisible_ o no en la colección.